# Create array of PDF files in directory that start with the letters "AB"

Tags: vba, ms-access, filenames

I'm trying to create a list of files in a specific directory folder where I am renaming the files, but because there is a chance some files should not be renamed, I only need to rename the PDF files that begin with the letters "AB".

The renaming works fine, I just need to make sure it only renames specific files.

```
Private Sub CMD_RENAME_FILES_Click()
On Error GoTo CMD_RENAME_FILES_ERR

    Dim varDir As String

    varDir = Me.TXT_BILLING_STATEMENT_PATH

    If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to rename all of the files in the directory " & "'" & varDir & "'", vbYesNo, "Confirm") = vbNo Then
        Exit Sub
    Else

    Dim strFileName, varDateString As String
    Dim strFolder As String: strFolder = Nz(Me.TXT_BILLING_STATEMENT_PATH, "Z:\")
    Dim strFileSpec As String: strFileSpec = strFolder & "*.pdf"
    Dim FileList() As String
    Dim intFoundFiles As Integer

    DoCmd.RunSQL ("UPDATE tblDirFileList SET tblDirFileList.RenameSelection = -1 WHERE FileName LIKE 'AB*'")

    strFileName = Dir(strFileSpec, "AB*.PDF") 'THIS AB* DOESN'T WORK"
    varDateString = Format(Date, "mmddyy")

        Do While Len(strFileName) > 0

            ReDim Preserve FileList(intFoundFiles)

            FileList(intFoundFiles) = strFileName
            intFoundFiles = intFoundFiles + 1
            varLoanNumString = Mid(strFileName, 4, 9)
            varNewStrFile = varLoanNumString & " - BILL STMT - " & varDateString & ".pdf"
            On Error Resume Next
            Name strFolder & strFileName As strFolder & varNewStrFile

            strFileName = Dir

        Loop

    Call CMD_GET_FILE_NAMES_Click

    End If

CMD_RENAME_FILES_ERR_EXIT:
    Exit Sub

CMD_RENAME_FILES_ERR:
    Call LogError(Err.Number, Err.Description, "CMD_RENAME_FILES_Click()")
    MsgBox "Error: (" & Err.Number & ") " & Err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume CMD_RENAME_FILES_ERR_EXIT

End Sub
```

Comment: `Dir(strFolder & "AB*.pdf")` should work

Comment: @TimWilliams Are you saying that what he has now *should* work, or are you pointing out that the issue is the uppercase `PDF` in the above example?

Comment: OP is using `Dir(strFileSpec, "AB*.PDF")` which will not work: that's not what the second parameter is for.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dir-function

Comment: I Figured it out, just putting in a like statement did the trick...  ' varFindString = "BS"
        
       Do While Len(strFileName) > 0
            Debug.Print strFileName
            If strFileName Like "*" & varFindString & "*" Then '